# how do I collect the function return in load

Tags: function, variables, lua, runtime-error

I'm now starting to study the `load()` function in lua, and I'm having trouble getting the value that the function returns

I tried these two ways to execute a function with `load()` and collect their value

```lua
function sumvalues()
    return 5+3
end

local func = "sumvalues()"

print(load(func))

local func = "return 5+3"

print(load(func))
```

but they only return the function, not the value returned from them

```lua
function: 0000000000cf0e50
function: 0000000000cf0df0
```

does anyone know **how I can perform a function with `load()` and collect their `return`?**

I also wanted to know how I do to collect a variable using a string with the same name as the variable in `load()`, I tried to do this:

```lua
hello = "Hello World"

print(load("hello"))
```

but he gives this error:

```lua
nil [string "hello"]:1: syntax error near <eof>
```

would anyone know how i can do this wonder? thanks for your attention !

Comment: If `load` returns a function, perhaps you should call it? `print(load("return 5+3")())` seems promising....

Comment: @exnihilo it worked, thank you very much for the wonderful answer <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a string to `load`, the chunk is compiled (in the global environment) and a function is returned that executes that chunk. In order to execute that chunk, you have to call the function:

```
> function sumvalues()
>> return 5+3
>> end
> func = "return sumvalues()"
> load(func)
function: 0x55e069c2a490
> load(func)()
8
```

Here `func` is a string that is taken as a chunk and compiled by `load` as the body of a function which returns the value returned from calling `sumvalues`. Note that since `load` compiles its chunks in the global environment, `local func = "return sumvalues()"` will not work, because then `func` would not be visible to `load`.

Another example:

```
> hello = "return 'Hello World'"
> load(hello)()
Hello World
> print(load(hello))
function: 0x55e069c53580
> print(load(hello)())
Hello World
```

Here, the chunk `"return 'Hello World'"` is compiled to a function that returns the string `'Hello World'`. You can call that function, print the value of that function, or print the value returned by calling that function.

If it seems like too much work to have to prepend `"return "` on the front of the code string, you could make a function like `chunkify`:

```
function chunkify (s)
  return "return " .. s
end

> load(chunkify("5+3"))()
8
> load(chunkify("'Hello World'"))()
Hello World
```

You are still passing a string containing the code that you want to run, so any strings within that code need to be quoted, too.

```
> load(chunkify("function (x) return 2*x end"))()(21)
42
```

The function returned by `load` does not take any arguments, but you can create such a function using `load` by compiling a chunk that itself returns a function that *does* take arguments. The function returned by `load` will have to be called in order to access the real function of interest. Above, see that the function returned by `load` is called with the first `()`, and the following `(21)` calls the function returned by the chunk.